# How to disable code folding for coq?

Tags: major-mode, code-folding

When I do `isearch` on the buffer having coq mode it somehow executes code folding,
something like `(... *)...`

I have tried to use `(setq company-coq-disabled-features '(code-folding))` for disabling code folding, but it didn't help (the code folding face was changed from `[...]` to `...` though).

Any ideas how to disable a code folding completely?

My full emacs setup for Coq:

```
;; Coq
(setq overlay-arrow-string "")
(setq company-coq-disabled-features '(code-folding))

(add-hook 'coq-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-fira-code-symbol-keywords)
            (company-coq-mode)))

(add-hook 'coq-goals-mode-hook #'add-fira-code-symbol-keywords)
(add-hook 'coq-response-mode-hook #'add-fira-code-symbol-keywords)

(setq proofgeneral (shell-command-to-string "printf \"$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(which proofgeneral))))/share/emacs/site-lisp/ProofGeneral/generic/proof-site\""))
(load proofgeneral)
```

Comment: OK, I found the workaround − to use `swiper` instead of `isearch` for coq files xD